# What's the difference between 扣好安全带 (kòuhǎo ānquándài) and 系好安全带 (jìhǎo ānquándài), which both seem to mean "fasten seatbelt"?

Tags: word-choice, usage, difference, synonyms

On the plane I see 就座后扣好安全带 (jiù zuòhòu kòuhǎo ānquándài) which is translated to "fasten seatbelt while seated".

[image: 就座后扣好安全带]

On the bus I see 上车请系好安全带 (shàngchē qǐng jìhǎo ānquándài) which I think translates to something like "after boarding the bus, please fasten seatbelts"

[image: 上车请系好安全带]

**Question**: What's the difference between 扣好安全带 (kòuhǎo ānquándài) and 系好安全带 (jìhǎo ānquándài), which both seem to mean "fasten seatbelt"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

扣 means to " to hook / to buckle" 
"扣好安全帶" means "buckle up the seatbelt "

系 means "to tie /to fasten" 
"系好安全帶" means to " fasten the seatbelt "

Although there are many ways to fasten a belt to something, when it comes to seatbelt, the only way to fasten it to the seat, is to buckle it up. Therefore, 系好安全帶 and 扣好安全帶 are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

扣好 is more like "to buckle up", we use this word because normally there is something like a buckle on the safe belt. 
系好 is more like "to knot", we use this word because normally the safe belt is shaped as a piece of string.

It works both ways, just sounds different.