# Does the word '攬' in Mandarin carry the meaning of "to loop ~ around"?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, meaning-in-context, cantonese

[This question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/whats-the-difference-between-%E6%89%A3%E5%A5%BD%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8%E5%B8%A6-k%C3%B2uh%C7%8Eo-%C4%81nqu%C3%A1nd%C3%A0i-and-%E7%B3%BB%E5%A5%BD%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8%E5%B8%A6-j%C3%ACh%C7%8Eo-%C4%81nqu%C3%A1nd%C3%A0/23935#23935) reminded me the different ways Cantonese say "fasten the safety belt"

Cantonese only say:

1. "攬安全帶" (loop the safety belt around oneself)
2. "綁安全帶" (tie the safety belt)
3. "扣安全帶" (buckle up the safety belt)

But we don't say "系安全帶" (fasten the safety belt)

On the other hand, I don't think Mandarin speakers say "綁安全帶" or "攬安全帶"  like Cantonese speakers do.

So my question is : Does the word '攬' in Mandarin carry the meaning of " **to loop ~ around**" too? Or it is Cantonese only as I suspected?

> 攬 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2151/
>
> *[粵] laam6 [國] lan3*
>
> *loop (scarf, belt, etc) around*

Some examples of 攬 /laam6/  as 'loop ~around' in Cantonese :

1. "佢沖完涼**攬**條大毛巾喺頸就返房" "She just **looped** (hung) a bath towel **around** her neck and went back to her room after taking a bath."
2. "冬天要**攬**條頸巾至好出街" = "Need to **loop** a scarf **around** the neck before go out in winter."

Comment: 揽 bkrs；to monopolize
to seize
to take into one’s arms
to embrace
to fasten (with a rope etc)
to take on (responsibility etc)
to canvass jukuu：1.  She twined her arms round [around] me.
 她用手臂揽住我。
 
    
2.  She clasped her child to her bosom.
 她把孩子紧紧揽在怀里。
 
  
  
3.  Her arms lapped her little son in.
 她背小儿子揽在怀里。

Answer (score 2):

Explanation from [zdic](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/63FD.htm):

> 1. 把持：～持。独～大权。
>   　2. 拉到自己这方面或自己身上来：包～。招～。承～。～客。～活儿。
>   　3. 搂，捆：把孩子～在怀里。
>   　4. 取：～秀。～胜。摘星～月。

From this and some other dictionaries (which may not be online) and my personal experience, I think 揽 in Mandarin does not have the usage you asked in Cantonese.

Answer (score 0):

The word '攬' in Mandarin does not carry the meaning of " to loop ~ around". It is probably Cantonese only as you suspected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Cantonese. but 揽 in Mandarin is mostly used in a scenario, where you want "pull sb. into your arms" to show yr affection. it definitely has some other meaning too, but the idea of 揽 is kinda like "to gather or collect all the things you want (image you pull everything you want around you into your arms.)"

Answer (score 0):

Only with your arms.

揽客(wave your arms , or pull others)

揽在怀里