# When is 系 pronounced xì/xi and when is it pronounced jì？

Tags: usage, pronunciation

A commonly used phrase is 没关系 (méiguānxi) which means "it doesn't matter"; it's used respond to 谢谢 (thank you) and 对不起 (sorry).

I found in [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/23931/8099) that 系 can also be pronounced jì, as in 系好安全带 (jìhǎo ānquándài) meaning "fasten your seatbelt".

This means [系](http://dict.cn/%E7%B3%BB) is a [多音字](https://baike.so.com/doc/1543904-1632144.html) (duō yīnzì) or a [heteronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_%28linguistics%29) (multiple pronunciation word).

**Question**: When is 系 pronounced xì/xi and when is it pronounced jì？

Doing a bit of Googling, I find:

- [中文系](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E7%B3%BB) = Zhōngwén xì (Chinese department)
- [太阳系](http://dict.cn/%E5%A4%AA%E9%98%B3%E7%B3%BB) = tài yáng xì (solar system)
- [系统](http://dict.cn/%E7%B3%BB%E7%BB%9F) = xì tǒng (system)
- [联系](http://dict.cn/%E8%81%94%E7%B3%BB) = lián xì (to contact)

It looks like xì/xi is the default pronunciation.  I didn't find much with jì, except possibly 系好[鞋带](http://dict.cn/%E9%9E%8B%E5%B8%A6) (jìhǎo xiédài) = "tie your shoes".

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/chinese-english/%E7%B3%BB

Comment: basically,  系 jì is used as a verb only.  xì is used as nouns, when xì is used as a verb standalone, it can be linking verb only 此人xì該公司主管, all xì in other verbs are not used standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**系**] is a traditional character as well as the simplified form for both [**繫**]  and [**係**]

没关**系** = 沒關**係**

中文**系** = 中文**系**

**系**统 = **系**統

联**系** = 聯**繫**

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2831/
>
> 系
>
> Pinyin: xi4
>
> [1] system; series; set
>
> [2] department; faculty

~

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2881/
>
> 繫
>
> Pinyin:  xi4 | ji4
>
> [1] tie; connect; fasten; bind up
>
> [2] relate to; bear on; depend on
>
> [3] be concerned; miss; bind to
>
> [粵] hai6 | [國] ji4
>
> button up; wear; knot

~

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/601/
>
> 係
>
> Pinyin:  xi4
>
> [1] [粵] [v] to be; is; are
>
> [2] [粵] yes, it is; indeed; right; positive
>
> [3] [n] relation; relationship; consequence

~

> *Question: When is 系 pronounced xì/xi and when is it pronounced jì？*

- 系 is pronounced /xi4/ when it is a traditional character (no difference in simplified form ), and means: system; department
- 系 is pronounced /xi4/ when it is the simplified form of 係, and means: relation; relationship; consequence
- 系 is pronounced /ji4/ when it is the simplified form of 繫, and means: button up; wear; knot

Answer (score 1):

I think you already got it.

Most of time, it's pronounced as xì/xi 系. When pronounced as（jì）, it means 'fasten' and 'tie'.  系安全带. and 系鞋带. are good examples.

Answer (score 0):

1. 系:This is a multiple pronunciation word.
2. 系[xì] 系统；世系。谱系；直系亲属。 某些学科中分类的名称。汉藏语系；印欧语系。 高等学校按专业性质设置的教学行政单位。数学系；历史系。 地质学名词。地层系统分类的第二级，小于界，相当于地质年代的纪。 姓。System;Lineage.Spectrum;Immediate family.The names of categories in certain subjects. Sino-tibetan language family; Indo-european. The teaching administrative unit of higher education is set according to the professional nature.Department of mathematics;The history department.Geological terms.The second level of stratigraphic system classification is less than the boundary, which is equivalent to the period of geological time.Last name.
3. 系[xì]是。联缀，涉及，关系。挂念，牵记。[xì] is.Affix, involving, relation.Hang up, worry。
4. 系[jì]打结或扣上。Tie [ji] knots or buckles.